# Map signal strength on a free dataset

Tags: mapping, openstreetmap, signal-strength

I'm looking for some kind of tool to generate a map (on openstreemap basis) with (colored) signalstrength points generated from a scan (not related to wlan, but quite similar to gpsmap from kismet). The input data is right now in a .kml file but converting this before won't be a problem. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

hm you can use Openlayers (http://www.openlayers.org/)
that understands KML (http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/KML-js.html)

here is an example: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml-layer.html